# What is the best way to write a reply to a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, best-practice

I see at least 3 ways to **reply to a comment** while mentioning the user:

1. `@user: Bla-bla-bla`
2. `@user, Bla-bla-bla`
3. `@user - Bla-bla-bla`

Which one is the proper or the **best way to do it?**

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter how you embed the @mention into your comment.

You can even put it somewhere in the middle of your sentence or at the end too, although at the beginning makes it easier to see who you are addressing at once glance, if multiple people are discussing.

Just remember that you can only mention one user per comment, and that the user has to have interacted with that post before to be mentionable. If it works, there will be a little autocomplete-popup above your cursor while you are typing a mention.

Comment: *"If it works, there will be a little autocomplete-popup above your cursor while you are typing a mention."* Doesn't it work for mentioning users who have edited the post, even though the UI doesn't autocomplete in that case?

Comment: Could be. I also believe editing makes you mentionable, but not sure if the autocomplete is hidden for that. Would have to try... or find an up to date meta post explaining it :)